# How to pass a variant of Jquery to a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

I'm begginer in Jquery and Javascript, 
I need to know if it is possible to send the value of a jquery variable to javascript.
I have this code in Jquery:

```
var value;
    $('#cb-tab').on("click", function () {
       value = $(this).data("valor" , 2);
       console.log(value);
    });
```

How do I make the "value" parameter can be sent to a function in javascript.

Comment: Just like you are passing to `console.log`

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library not a separate programming language javascript. It makes certain things easier (or just faster) to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value as an argument to the function you need to call:

```
$('#cb-tab').on("click", function() {
  var value = $(this).data("valor");
  someFunction(value);
});

function someFunction(value) {
    alert("the value is: " + value);
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/69zkturp/**